# PHP preg_split, split at | and check for minimum 3 chars

Tags: php, regex

I want to separate at the "|" and check the length to at least 3 characters

```
$input_line = "test test | teste test test3 | test test 4"

preg_split('/(.\|.)/', $input_line);

// Have tried: preg_split('/(.\|.)^[a-z0-9*]{3}$/', $input_line);
```

Can anybody help me?
https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/AdQ

Comment: Why regular expressions? `explode` would be sufficient.

Comment: You need each element after split to be at least three characters long?

Comment: Yes, but i have 2 or 3 possible chars to "explode". "|", "\n". What do you mean if its more than 2-3? maybe it could be more.

Comment: I'm asking because you mentioned *"I want to separate at the | and check the length to at least 3 characters"*. How do we exactly interpretate that?

Comment: Yes, each element should have at least 3 characters.

Comment: So would `preg_match_all('/\b[^|]{3,}\b/', $input_lines, $output_array);` help?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It can be either a | or \n as a separator. and the string in between should have at least 3 characters.

Comment: @JvdV for preg_match_all its ok. But i need preg_split :)

Comment: You can't do this with ONLY preg_split.

Comment: @decepter maybe try something like `(?:[^|]{3,})(\|)` to lookahead to get the `|` after 3 non-| chars?

Comment: @David542 sorry not working. my resolution ist now: 

`$this->dataArray = preg_split('/(\n|\s\|\s)/',$this->data, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);  
    
    foreach($this->dataArray as $key => $val) {  
     if(strlen($val) <= 4) {            
      unset($this->dataArray[$key]);          
      }         
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think doing this in a regex might not be the best tool for the job, but if you want to use it here might be a possibility:

```
(?:^|\|)           # start at the start of a line or with a `|`
([^|]{3,})         # before the next '|', make sure it has length >= 3
(?:\||$|\n)        # up until the next '|' or '\n' or '$'
```

[image]

https://regex101.com/r/Pz3YCH/1

Again though, I think doing a string split would be much better though.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not `preg_match` and `preg_split` is different. https://3v4l.org/QdCAB

Comment: @AbraCadaver you are right. i will check the length after the split. have also tried to cover  within the preg_split.

Comment: Well this one doesn't work, check the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with only `preg_split`.  You can either use `preg_match` or split and filter:

```
$result = preg_split('/(\||\n)/', $input_line);
$result = array_filter($result, function($v) { return strlen($v) > 2; });
```

- Split on `|` (must be escaped) `\|` OR `|` `\n`
- Filter out strings less than 3 characters

If the spaces padding the `|` don't count as characters then add the spaces to the pattern `/\s(\||\n)\s/` or `trim` them with `array_map` or `array_walk`.